# How to enable disabled submit button after any one of the radioButton of RadioGroup?

Tags: android, android-radiogroup

Here I am trying to make an app where I have 4 options on my MainActivity Screen, User should able to Click on submit only when one of the radio button is selected.(OTHERWISE NOT), which help me to **avoid null pointer Exception** while submitting the option.

============================= **MainActivity.java**====================

```
    package com.Xapp.radiobuttondemo;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        RadioGroup radioGroup;
        Button submit;
        TextView tv;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            submit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
            radioGroup=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioOptions);

            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
            {
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


                    boolean is=group.isActivated();  //This must be something else,Please suggest
                     if(is==true)
                      {
                          submit.setEnabled(true);
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          submit.setEnabled(false);
                      }             
                }

            });
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

==============================**activity_main.xml**============================

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioOptions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/option1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/option2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/option3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/option4" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

=======================================**strings.xml**=================================

```
<string name="app_name">RadioButtonDemo</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Select One</string>
<string name="option1">Red</string>
<string name="option2">Blue</string>
<string name="option3">Green</string>
<string name="option4">Pink</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are writing Button **ENABLE OR DISABLE** code inside **CheckChanged** Event of Radiogroup which will never call if any radio button is not selected.

Updated code:::::
try the below code for what you want.

```
// get selected radio button from radioGroup
int selectedId = radioOptions.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

if(selectedId == null || selectedId < 1)
{
   submit.setEnabled(false);
}
else
{
  submit.setEnabled(true);
 }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I don't know if you replaced my RadioGroup object "group" with your "readioButton" object.
I don't want to listen each RadioButton, instead of that I want to listen RadioGroup, so that if anyone of the RadioButton get checked, I can do the enable button task.

Comment: selectedId is integer type, we can't do == with null. do we??

Comment: yes to compare integer with null `==` is the correct way.

Comment: We can't do that. Please try to do copy-paste of my code and help me out.

Comment: try to add this code `selectedId < 1` in `if condition`. check my updates.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton1) {
                    //do something
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton2) {
              //do something
```

Comment: I don't want to use like you wrote or below I were trying.if(radioButton.getId()==R.id.radioButton1| radioButton.getId()==R.id.radioButton2|radioButton.getId()==R.id.radioButton3|radioButton.getId()==R.id.radioButton4)
               {
                submit.setEnabled(true);
               }
               else
               {
                submit.setEnabled(false);
               }

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think, that if you receive a OnCheckChanged event, is because one of the radiobutton was selected. 
OnCheckChanged -> "Called when the checked radio button has changed."
So there is no need to check, because one of then was already selected.

You don't need to do this:

```
if(is==true)
                  {
                      submit.setEnabled(true);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      submit.setEnabled(false);
                  }
```

Because on a radiogroup once you select one of then, then always there will be one selected.

Comment: If I don't try to do this and the user clicks on the submit button without selecting any of the radioButton then I'll get Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: Umm, umm you can set your as:
setEnabled(false) at the onCreate or you can do disable it at the design form. That the button will be disabled at the beginning, and then you enable it in the onCheckedChanged event.